# How to connect to a Cluster prommatically

Tags: java, cassandra

Am successfully installed `cassandra` and when i testing with "`connect localhost/9160;`" it is working fine for me.I want connect with different IP address/Port.I was changed the `listen_address` in `cassandra.yaml` file and restarted the server and tested it showing below error.

```
 Exception retrieving information about the cassandra node, check you have connected to the thrift port.

org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Read a negative frame size (-21
13929216)!
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTranspo
rt.java:133)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.ja
va:101)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.ja
va:362)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.ja
va:284)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryPr
otocol.java:191)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_describe_cluster_na
me(Cassandra.java:1206)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.describe_cluster_name(Ca
ssandra.java:1194)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.connect(CliMain.java:138)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeConnect(CliClient.java:2393
)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeCLIStatement(CliClient.java
:282)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.processStatementInteractive(CliMain.
java:201)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:331)
```

It is really helpful for me.Sorry my bad English..

Answer (score 0):

If the only parameter you changed is `listen_address`, then you still need to use port 9160 to connect with cassandra-cli. If you want to change that port as well, then you need to adjust the `rpc_port` in `cassandra.yaml` accordingly. listen_address defines the port that two Cassandra nodes would communicate over. It is independent of the port used for Thrift clients (like cassandra-cli).